# How to find angular-route is already installed in my machine using npm

Tags: angularjs, windows, npm, ngroute

I am a beginner to angular js and learned how to use directives. Now, as part of learning MVC model I want to separate models from view for that, I have created respective html and js file. 
 On angular docs I understood in order to make communication between model and views, we need to use 'ngroute', so I tried to install it using npm command as follows

```
C:\npm install angular-route
```

I have received the following error as an output

```
C:\
`-- angular-route@1.5.8

npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\package.json'
npm WARN !invalid#1 No description
npm WARN !invalid#1 No repository field.
npm WARN !invalid#1 No README data

npm WARN !invalid#1 No license field.
```

A few questions in my head now, 
   1) Do we need to install ngroute (or anyother installations using npm) from particular directory.?
   2) How do we find if the packages is already installed using 'npm'.? (in my case it is ngroute)

I am currently working on Windows8 OS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First answers on your questions:

1. Yes, you mostly need to run commands like 'npm install' in the root folder of your project. Normally this is the top folder of your project which contains the 'package.json' file. In your case you run it in the 'C:\' which obviously is not correct.
2. When some modules have been already installed in the project, then in the root folder of your project you should have a 'node_modules' directory where the installed modules appear as a sub-folders.

Now other answers:

1. You actually got warnings and not errors from the 'npm install', i.e. it actually did the job. Check the 'C:\node_modules\' folder, there should be an 'angular-route' sub-folder with the module (yet may not be there when you have no permission to write in the root of the 'C:\').
2. 'package.json' is the main configuration file for npm in a project. All project dependencies normally have to be specified there, so that then you just type 'npm install' (without parameters) in the root folder of the project to get all needed libs installed. But note, that some people may install angular and etc. via some other packet manager. Frequently it is bower, so then 'package.json' specifies only project processing tools (which convert SCSS->CSS, minify code, copy files during build etc.), whereas the javascript libraries used in the project itself, are specified elsewhere (e.g. in the bower.json for bower; but bower is a bit oldish/unnecessary in these days, there are many other alternatives e.g. webpack or just node itself).
3. Probably you already use one, but if not, then I recommend you to use one of the numerous 'angular seed' projects. E.g.: [the Angular 1.5 seed (with bower)](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed), [the Angular2 seed](https://github.com/angular/angular2-seed).

Answer (score 1):

Try `npm -v package` So for you, `npm -v angular-route` for example.